# How to create a list of sublists in Lisp without map?

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, sublist

I'm trying to make a function that creates a list of all sublists in the given list.

What I mean is, when I've got a list:

```
(4 (a g b) g (1 2 3) g (4 5 6))
```

I want a list:

```
((a g b) (1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

What I have got at the moment:

```
(defun unterlisten_zurueckgeben (lst)
  (let (unterlisten)
    (cond ((endp lst) nil)
          ((listp (first lst))
           (or (unterlisten_zurueckgeben (first lst)) 
               (setq unterlisten (cons (first lst) (unterlisten_zurueckgeben (rest lst))))))
          (t (unterlisten_zurueckgeben (rest lst))))
    unterlisten))
```

doesn't seem to work and I can't find my mistake.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "a list of sublists in the list". You should provide an example.

Comment: What I mean is, when I've got a list: `(4 (a g b) g (1 2 3) g (4 5 6))` I want a list: `((a g b) (1 2 3) (4 5 6))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to keep only sublist. You can easily do that with [`remove-if`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_removecm__elete-if-not.html):

```lisp
(defun remove-atoms (lst)
  (remove-if #'atom lst))
```

In your recursive code there is a problem with:

```lisp
(or (unterlisten_zurueckgeben (first lst)) 
    (setq unterlisten (cons (first lst) 
                            (unterlisten_zurueckgeben (rest lst))))))
```

Here if the result of `(unterlisten_zurueckgeben (first lst))` is not an empty list (eg. a list with a list) then it will be the result of the whole thing.

If it's not `nil`, then you change the **local** binding `underlisten` to what seems to be an ok result.

Since the `cond` is **not** the tail expression. The result of the function is always whatever `underlisten` is. Thus for the default case where you just recurse with the rest of the list the result is never returned since it will return `nil` (the initial value of `underlisten`).

Thus even your recursive roll-your-own solution is far more complex than it needs to be:

```lisp
(defun remove-atoms (lst)
  (cond ((endp lst) nil)
        ((listp (first lst))
         (cons (first lst) (remove-atoms (rest lst))))
        (t (remove-atoms (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: After thinking a long while I realized that while this, and the second answer too, is the answer to my question, the answer doesn't help me in the big picture as the question I posed was not what would help me solve my overall problem.

Comment: @EviLGaMer Now, thats what is called a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (ie. Instead of posing your actual problem you pose a problem related to a possible solution)

Comment: Finished what I tried to do in three lines after long and hard thinking. What I wanted to do is to write a function that would simplify an arithmetic expression written as a list with sublists aka `(+ 3 5 (- 7 4) x 8 9 (* 3 5 f))` as far as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If so you can write:

```
(defun unterlisten-zurueckgeben (lst)
    (remove-if-not #'listp lst))
 ; or use #'consp if you don't want empty sublists
```

Note, that in Lisp the preferred way for combining identifiers is to use dashes instead of underscores.